# how to perform a multi sql search via php in one field

Tags: php, sql, select, count, where-clause

i am using this sql search to find a title and artist in my database. I have on field containing infos like "ref.1570 title artist.mp4". When I do the search it works but in one direction only, i would like to get the result whatever the order i do the search... to be more precise if i search "title artist" no problem i found it. If i search "artist title" no way ... how can you help me making php sql search both directions ?

Best regards and thank you for your help.
Phil

i am using this code :

```
 if ($search != null) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE (`file`LIKE "%' . $search . '%")';
        $sqlCount = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `catalog` WHERE (`file`LIKE "%' . $search . '%")';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split keyword `$search` with `space` and append with `Like` statement in the query. Eg:

```
if ($search != null) {
    $keywords=explode(" ",$search);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE 1=1'; // just to append OR condition.This won't affect anything as the condition will always be true.
    $sqlCount = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `catalog` WHERE 1=1 ';
    foreach($keywords as $key){
        if(!empty($key)){
            $sql.=' And file Like \'%'.$key.'\%';
            $sqlCount.=' And file Like \'%'.$key.'\%';
        }
    } 

}
```

I believe this will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't get around a foreach:

```
if ($search != null) {
    $arrayOfSearchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE ';
    $sqlCount = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `catalog` WHERE ';
    $termNumber = 0;

    foreach ($arrayOfSearchTerms as $term) {
        $addingSql = '';
        if ($termNumber > 0) {
            $addingSql = ' OR ';
        }
        $addingSql .= '(`file` LIKE "%') . $term . '%")';
        $sql .= $addingSql;
        $sqlCount = $addingSql;
        $termNumber++;
    }
}
```

You need to iterate over your search terms and add this terms into your 'LIKE'-Statement

Comment: $termNumber is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this research: it does a LIKE %word% for every word. If you want more powerfull research you should use tools like elasticsearch etc...
This way you could do:

```
$parts = explode(" ",$search)
$queryParts = array();

foreach ($parts as $part) {
   $queryParts[] = `artist`LIKE "%' . $part . '%" ;
}
// this way we can have like %artist% AND like %title%
$querySearch= implode(" AND ", $queryParts); 

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE (". $querySearch .")';
$sqlCount = 'SELECT count(*) FROM `catalog` WHERE (`". $querySearch .")';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have solved my problem i know now hos to correctly explode a request into variables ..

```
$search = $name;
  $explode=explode(" ",$search);

  print_r (explode(" ",$explode));
```

and then i use my sql request like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE (`idc` LIKE "%' . $search . '%" OR `file` LIKE "%' . $search . '%" OR `title` LIKE "%' . $explode[0] . '%" AND `artist`LIKE "%' . $explode[1] . '% " OR `artist`LIKE "%' . $explode[0] . '%" AND `title`LIKE "%' . $explode[1] . '%")';
```

and it is working !

COOL

Answer (score -1):

Use the multi query functions,

in mysqli should be : mysqli_multi_query();

More info on : [Mysqli Multiquery](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)